# sql server join and select top 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have one customer table and one address table.For each customer there should be multiple address in address Table
I need A stored procedure to select a customer details and his  address on top from address table 
parameter to select customer is companyID

```
SELECT top 1  s.Addr1 as ShipAddress_Addr1,s.Addr2 as  ShipAddress_Addr2,s.Addr3 as ShipAddress_Addr3,
    s.Addr4 as ShipAddress_Addr4,s.Addr5 as ShipAddress_Addr5,
    s.City as ShipAddress_City,s.[state] as ShipAddress_State,s.PostalCode as ShipAddress_PostalCode,
    s.Country as ShipAddress_Country,s.Note as ShipAddress_Note ,c.CustomerID,c.[TimeCreated], c.[FullName],c.FirstName,c.LastName,c.Phone, c.Email, 
    c.BillAddress_Addr1, c.[BillAddress_Addr2],c. [BillAddress_Addr3],c. [BillAddress_Addr4],c.[BillAddress_Addr5],
     c.BillAddress_City,c.BillAddress_State,c.BillAddress_PostalCode,c.BillAddress_Country,c.BillAddress_Note
        FROM   Customer c left join [dbo].[CustomerShipToAddress] s on s.customerListID=c.CustomerID    
    WHERE c.IsActive = 1 and c.CompanyID = @CompanyID
```

Comment: And what did you try before asking a question?

Comment: Have a look at `CROSS APPLY` and `TOP`. Have a go yourself first and if you don't succeed, please post your attempt and we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Note that "top 1" will be meaningless/random unless you specify ORDER BY on a useful column of the address table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `outer apply` the latest address for each customer like this:

```
select c.customerid, c.name, c.accno, c.txnid, ta.add1, ta.add2
from customertable c
outer apply (select top 1 a.add1, a.add2 from addresstable a where a.customerid = c.customerid order by a.addressid desc) ta
```

The sub-query in the outer apply with always return 0 or 1 rows for each customer, so it will not cause duplication of rows when you join it with `customertable`.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT TOP 1, c.customerid, c.name, a.add1  FROM customertable c, addresstable a WHERE c.customerid == a.customerid
```

this will return the first row basically. this is what you are asking for, but not what you mean i assume.

if you want to look this up for a specific customer use

```
SELECT TOP 1, c.customerid, c.name, a.add1  FROM customertable c, addresstable a WHERE c.customerid == a.customerid AND c.customerid == "yourcustomerid"
```

or even

```
SELECT c.customerid, c.name, DISTINCT a.add1  FROM customertable c, addresstable a WHERE c.customerid == a.customerid
```

Comment: This won't return customers without an address. Also it will return only one row, even if there are multiple customers. And the third query isn't even a valid T-SQL.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov i am aware, i was already editing my answer. however, this is what the OP is asking. You cant blame me for the formulation of the question right.